# When I use gettext function in codeigniter the browser show ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, gettext

I need to use gettext in my new application, but when I try to use this

```
<input type="submit" value='<?php echo _('Enviar'); ?>'>
```

The Browser show my this legend

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

It didn't show me an error, even when I call a function that doesn't exist, show me this, but if I remove the functions, the form load fine

Comment: clear the cache from browser and restart xampp[what ever] you are using this may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

different factors cause Error net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, there is no one answer for everyone.

While searching On internet it's seems that you get this error in chrome browsers.

I have suggested very common way to solve this problem[in comment], i am including some links have look on them.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/E9OS9mS6yc8

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/2EDWkwK2Go8

[PHP error, no data received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128134/php-error-no-data-received)

**What does this error actually means?**

The message indicates a data transfer issue that is sometimes difficult to correct as it may not always be caused on your end.

**Why this error is Caused?**

[have a look upon this](https://vimeo.com/60824619)

For more details have a look on this [LINK](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/01/07/how-to-fix-the-no-data-received-error-in-google-chrome/)