# Basic REST calls to WordPress V2 API with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, get

I'm trying to get a basic query going with the new V2 API and Angular in WordPress 4.4.1. Perhaps someone can help me understand why the URL, `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, gives a JSON response with a 404.

Browsing to that URL gives me JSON like this:

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}
```

And here is the JavaScript I'm using to make that .GET

```
var base    = 'http://localhost:8888/recruitler';
var posts   = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
var user    = '/wp-json/wp/v2/users/'; // append user id
var s       = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[s]='; // append search term

// basic HTTP call with Angular
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

app.factory('myService', function($http) {
    var myService = {
        async: function() {
          // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
          var promise = $http.get( base+posts ).then(function (response) {
            // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
            console.log(response);
            // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
            return response.data;
          });
          // Return the promise to the controller
          return promise;
        }
    };
  return myService;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService, $scope ) {
  // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside our own then function
    myService.async().then(function(d) {
        $scope.data = d;
    });
});
```

UPDATE:
This must be a local environment issue. Live websites work just fine. I've tested and this issue persists on all my local WAMP and MAMP dev sites. Restarting the server and or checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163190/1440240) got it working.

Answer (score 1):

the factory looks right, according to the rest-api docs you need pretty permalinks plugin as well in order to rest-api plugin use custom url rewrites https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/installation/

Comment: Oh wow you need that plugin as well? The API is kind of a mess huh? Now I'm getting `GET http://localhost:8888/recruitler/wp-json/wp/v2/posts net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: try with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: I've been playing with the URL and researching for 4 hours now... I have no idea how to use the API.

Comment: I just installed wordpress  on my laptop, I enabled numeric permalinks and added a sample .htaccess from https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess (I used the Subfolder Example). If you have your wp installation in a subfolder you new to change the  RewriteBase value. On my .htaccess it looks like this:  RewriteBase /wordpress/